# SQL left join - limit number of rows returned

Tags: mysql

I have a working SQL statement, but there is one issue within it I can't solve.
When I left join my table sites_photos there can be multiple matches on sp.sites_id = s.id, but I want the table to only return 1. Is this possible.

```
SELECT s.*, sp.photo
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN sites_photos sp
ON sp.sites_id = s.id
```

My output: 2 times id 30, but with different photo paths, I only want 1 returned for that id, or both bundled in one array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 30
        [url] => www.test.nl
        [name] => Aleve
        [date] => 2014-08-16
        [cms_active] => Y
        [archive] => N
        [photo] => 2014080812365920120214103601number_1.jpg
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 30
        [url] => www.test.nl
        [name] => Aleve
        [date] => 2014-08-16
        [cms_active] => Y
        [archive] => N
        [photo] => 20140811021102news.jpg
    )
)
```

Comment: If you use `mysql` as it is tagged you can `add group by s.id` ad it should give you the result with one photo per id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so,by using `GROUP_CONCAT` which will concatenate all the photos per site by and produces comma separated list of photos then you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` over result of `GROUP_CONCAT` to pick one photo,you can also add the criteria of order by in `GROUP_CONCAT` as `GROUP_CONCAT(sp.photo ORDER BY sp.id DESC)`

```
SELECT s.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(sp.photo),',',1) photo
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN sites_photos sp
ON sp.sites_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: Your SUBSTRING_INDEX works perfect, but if no match is found with the left join, the statement returns no data at all. Any tips on this?

Comment: @user2381011 can you provide sample dataset to test with it [@sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)